# Virtualbox error (NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED ) after Linux 4.20 and VBOX 6.0 update (Arch Linux)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, arch-linux

After upgrading my Arch Linux system (Linux 4.20) and rebooting it, it fails to start VBox (now Vbox 6.0) Error message is: NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED.

Vbox kernel modules are loaded (see below).

It seems everything ist fine, I don't know where to look for wrong config/install. If I do VBoxManage list -l I am getting same error messages below. /tmp folder is writeable for root and vboxuser

Any ideas?

```
vboxwebsrv -p 5678 -A null -H server.de
Oracle VM VirtualBox web service Version 6.0.0
(C) 2007-2018 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.
00:00:00.000097 main     VirtualBox web service 6.0.0 r127442 linux.amd64 (Dec 26 2018 21:56:59) release log
00:00:00.000100 main     Log opened 2019-01-02T20:17:34.687638000Z
00:00:00.000101 main     Build Type: release
00:00:00.000103 main     OS Product: Linux
00:00:00.000104 main     OS Release: 4.20.0-arch1-1-ARCH
00:00:00.000105 main     OS Version: #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 24 03:00:40 UTC 2018
00:00:00.000131 main     DMI Product Name: 
00:00:00.000141 main     DMI Product Version: 
00:00:00.000185 main     Host RAM: 15925MB (15.5GB) total, 10819MB (10.5GB) available
00:00:00.000189 main     Executable: /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxwebsrv
00:00:00.000189 main     Process ID: 13728
00:00:00.000190 main     Package type: LINUX_64BITS_GENERIC (OSE)
00:00:00.021361 main     IPC socket path: /tmp/.vbox-root-ipc/ipcd
vboxwebsrv: error: failed to create the VirtualBoxClient object!
vboxwebsrv: error: Code NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED (0x80040154) - Class not registered (extended info not available)
vboxwebsrv: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running or failed to start.
# lsmod | grep vbox                                                                                                                       
vboxnetflt             32768  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxpci                28672  0
vboxdrv               499712  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
```